# Search and replace with Notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

I am trying to replace this piece of code :

```
    <Group>
        <Group type="level"/>
        <Group type="started"/>
    </Group>
```

I tried this regex

```
   <Group>(*.?)</Group>
```

but its not working . Any one has a solution ?

Comment: did you check the 'dot matches newlines' option?

Comment: `*` should go after the `.`, no?

Comment: @OGHaza yes , but its still not working

Comment: @user3001909, do what peeskillet said too! `.*` not `*.`

Comment: When you say it is not working, what did it do?

Comment: @peeskillet this one doesn't work

Comment: @AdrianHHH Notepad++ does not find this piece of code , i tried every comboe ?*. , .*? , *.?

Comment: So you've tried `<Group>(.*?)</Group>` with the 'dot match newline' checkbox checked? On a mac right now so can't test.

Comment: @OGHaza yes , the program said no code was found 
http://imageshack.com/a/img707/7631/3ctp.png

Comment: Make sure you have checked both **Regular expression** and **Dot matches newline**. With that the **Find what** string `<Group>(.*?)</Group>` works for me.

Comment: Try matching against a single file that you know contains the pattern rather than doing a find in files.

Comment: From the PNG file, make sure that the directory is the one that contains the files. Try clicking **Follow currect doc**.

Comment: @All , somehow the problem was solved . It only works for one file at time , not for more .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `.` doesn't match newlines. You can replace it with `[\s\S]` or add     `(?s)` at the begining of the pattern (or before the dot) to set the dotall mode (where newlines are matched with `.` too):

```
<Group>(?s)(.*?)</Group>

<Group>([\s\S]*?)</Group>

<Group>(.*?)</Group>    # with the dotall checkbox checked
```

note: you have inverted the position of the dot with the position of the quantifier.

Comment: @user3001909: bigre! wait a minute I will test it.

Comment: @user3001909: What's strange! I have tested it and it works. Have you checked the regular expression checkbox ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you ! It works but only for one file at time . :)